# POST form data using AJAX and return object

Tags: ajax, post, request

I have created a form which has two inputs and a submit button. The form will post to a RESTful service which is all set up.

I want to use AJAX in order to POST to this RESTful service and then return the object so I can then validate the form.

The object will return something like this for an error and one similar for success

```
{"status":"error","message":"Incorrect username or password."}
```

My code is below. When i test I am using XAMPP on localhost:81. When I submit the form I receive this error.

```
 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.


<form name="login-form" id="login-form" method="post" action="SERVICEHERE"> 
                <label id="error">Sorry it seems your credentials are incorrect</label>
                <div class="inputBlock">
                  <label for="username">Username</label>
                  <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
                </div>
                <div class="inputBlock">
                  <label for="password">Password</label>
                  <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" id="submit" />
              </form>

$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#login-form").submit(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var formData = $("#login-form").serialize();
          console.log(formData);
          $.ajax({ 
            type: "GET", 
            url: $("#login-form").attr('action'),
            data: formData,
            success: function(data) {
              alert(data);
            }
          });    
        });
    });
```

Comment: what value did you use for SERVICEHERE ?

Comment: It returns a status of 200 and a type of XHR if that is any help?

Comment: Is it the same domain which generated this html form page ?

Comment: It is not it is a separate domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can't post content to a different domain from javascript. It's not allowed for security reasons, and it is blocked by your browser.

When you execute an XmlHttpRequest by your webpage's javascript to another domain, your browser sets your domain name in the `Origin` header in your request. That target domain has to respond with a header called `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` containing your domain as well, meaning it allows your domain's clients to call it. Otherwise the browser will block the call.

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

EDIT: There are ways to bypass the browser security and allow CORS all the time : https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/08/bypass-cors-errors-testing-apis-locally/

Comment: If I run the form without the Javscript attached. The end result is still a success or error on the specified URL depending on what I enter in the username and password boxes.

Comment: Is there a way I can return the echo'ed out message?

Comment: "For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests initiated from within scripts". So without javascript it's ok.

Comment: So there is no way for me to get the status message output by there side with the use of AJAX?

Comment: When the form is submitted it redirects to there server and outputs a message {"status":"error","message":"Incorrect username or password."}

Comment: Your browser will first send a "test" request, I believe of type OPTION, to verify if there is an answer, and if that answer has the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in it. If it doesn't, then all your XmlHttpRequests won't be sent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105388/discussion-between-harry-berry-and-nicomak).